# JSTree select_node event and checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jstree

I have a jstree in which I used the select_node event to toggle nodes(expand), and have therefore removed the toggle arrows in the tree since they look ugly and I've no need for them.

Now I've added the checkbox plugin to use within the tree, but have found the select_node event is disabled when the plugin is active.

How would I toggle my nodes with the checkbox plugin active, without re-adding the ugly toggle arrows? I could do it in the check/uncheck event, but I don't want to check/uncheck everytime I expand a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of jstree now allows for both checking and selecting node separately by either clicking on the check box or the node title.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jstree/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk - Get the latest version from there.
http://code.google.com/p/jstree/issues/detail?id=770&can=1&q=checkbox&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 2):

JsTree offers style [themes](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/themes) so you can define your own and load it.
You simply need to replace the sprite image and that's pretty much that.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of how to toggle a node when checkbox is active without using the arrows(or any image I might replace arrows with)

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the example tree as in http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox, with
arrows removed. You cant execute both a checkbox selection and branch toggling, on a click event,  without disrupting ui interaction. But, as non-leaf nodes don't carry model data 
(their checkboxes only serve as select-all/deselect-all function), you could remove the
checkboxes from them, redefining the click events over them as "toggle_node", while
leaving the rest unthouched.

You can remove the checkboxes on non-leaf li nodes and make a click event on them
toggle the leaves. That would accomplish your desired behaviour, but will remove
the "select all/deselect all" functionality of non-leaf nodes checkboxes.

Just add the lines below marked with "+", on the sample page.

```
    $("#demo1").jstree({ 
       "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "checkbox" ]
    });

+    $("#demo1 li").not(".jstree-leaf").each(function() {
+       $("a ins.jstree-checkbox", this).first().hide();
+       $("a", this).first().click(function(event) {
+          $("#demo1").jstree("toggle_node", "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id'));
+          event.stopPropagation();
+          event.preventDefault();
+       });
+    });
```